# How to solve such complicated integral involving Bessel function.

Tags: definite-integrals, exponential-function, bessel-functions

I am stucked in solving this integral that involves exponential, Bessel function and Power.

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(x-z)^{2m_1-1}\cdot z^{m_2+m_3-1}\cdot e^{\frac{m_1}{\Omega_1}(-2xz+z^2)}\cdot K_{m_2-m_3}\left(2\sqrt\frac{m_2m_3}{\Omega_2\Omega_3}z\right)dz$

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are $x, m_{1}, m_{2}, m_{3}, \Omega_{1}, \Omega_{2}, \Omega_{3}$ all constants? Also, what function is $K$?

Comment: Are you sure you wrote this correctly? As it stands I don't see the integral converging. Assuming $m_1 / \Omega_1$ to be positive, though of course I don't know that, the exponential term grows like $\exp(m_1 z^2/ \Omega)$ whereas the Bessel function decays as $\exp(-2Cz)$ where $C$ is the ratio of $m$s and $\Omega$s in the argument.

Comment: @wang , K is a Bessel function and m1, m2, m3, omega1,omega2,omega3 are shape and scale parameters of nakagami PDF and yes they are constant....

Comment: @rural reader, I think I had wrote correctly. I had obtained this   on solving the product of two nakagami PDF for independent but not necessarily identically distributed random variables and adding PDF of nakagami-m random variable to that product i.e., p= c+ a*b where a,b,c are independent but not necessarily identically distributed nakagami-m random variables